# What happens to second-level permissions when REVOKE GRANT is called PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Say a user, `u1` gives another user `u2` privilege to view a table in PostgreSQL and gives them `GRANT OPTION`:

```
GRANT SELECT ON t1 TO u1 WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Now, `u2` gives permission to another user, `u3`:

```
-- AS u2
GRANT SELECT ON t1 TO u3;
```

Now, `u2` changes positions in the organisation and their permissions change. Among them, their view permissions on `t1` are revoked:

```
-- As u1
REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON t1 FROM u2;
```

What happens to the permissions of `u3`?

---

Additional question: what happens to `u2` and `u3` if `u1`'s permissions are revoked instead?

```
REVOKE ALL ON t1 FROM u1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Privileges that somebody has granted because they have received the `GRANT OPTION` for a privilege, have a dependency on the original privilege.

To revoke the original privilege, you have to use the `CASCADE` option which will make the revocation cascade to all dependent privileges.

So no privilege can ever be “orphaned”.

A simple experiment:

- Create the table and the roles and give out privileges:

  ```
  test=# CREATE TABLE t1 (id integer PRIMARY KEY);
  CREATE TABLE
  test=# CREATE ROLE u1 LOGIN;
  CREATE ROLE
  test=# GRANT SELECT ON t1 TO u1 WITH GRANT OPTION;
  GRANT
  test=# CREATE ROLE u2 LOGIN;
  CREATE ROLE
  test=# CREATE ROLE u3 LOGIN;
  CREATE ROLE
  test=# SET ROLE u1;
  SET
  test=> GRANT SELECT ON t1 TO u2 WITH GRANT OPTION;
  GRANT
  test=> RESET ROLE;
  RESET
  test=# SET ROLE u2;
  SET
  test=> GRANT SELECT ON t1 TO u3 WITH GRANT OPTION;
  GRANT
  test=> RESET ROLE;
  RESET
  test=# \z t1
                                  Access privileges
   Schema | Name | Type  |     Access privileges     | Column privileges | Policies 
  --------+------+-------+---------------------------+-------------------+----------
   public | t1   | table | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres+|                   | 
          |      |       | u1=r*/postgres           +|                   | 
          |      |       | u2=r*/u1                 +|                   | 
          |      |       | u3=r*/u2                  |                   | 
  (1 row)
  ```
- Now, as `u1` revoke the `GRANT OPTION` from `u2`:

  ```
  test=# SET ROLE u1;
  SET
  test=> REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR SELECT ON t1 FROM u2;
  ERROR:  dependent privileges exist
  HINT:  Use CASCADE to revoke them too.
  test=> REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR SELECT ON t1 FROM u2 CASCADE;
  REVOKE
  test=> RESET ROLE;
  RESET
  test=# \z t1
                                  Access privileges
   Schema | Name | Type  |     Access privileges     | Column privileges | Policies 
  --------+------+-------+---------------------------+-------------------+----------
   public | t1   | table | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres+|                   | 
          |      |       | u1=r*/postgres           +|                   | 
          |      |       | u2=r/u1                   |                   | 
  (1 row)
  ```

  All the privileges that `u2` has dealt out have been revoked.
- Revoke all privileges from `u1`:

  ```
  test=# REVOKE SELECT ON t1 FROM u1;
  ERROR:  dependent privileges exist
  HINT:  Use CASCADE to revoke them too.
  test=# REVOKE SELECT ON t1 FROM u1 CASCADE;
  REVOKE
  test=# \z t1
                                  Access privileges
   Schema | Name | Type  |     Access privileges     | Column privileges | Policies 
  --------+------+-------+---------------------------+-------------------+----------
   public | t1   | table | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres |                   | 
  (1 row)
  ```

  All privileges directly or indirectly granted by `u1` are gone.